# mysql_query function only works with mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, google-visualization, mysql-num-rows

I have a very strange problem today. I have a section of code which queries a table based on a GET variable passed from a user input (pretty standard). 
However for this to work I have to include a redundant **mysql_num_rows** variable....

#### This Works;

```
   <?php
   1. $cat = strval($_GET['c']);
   2. $query = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE Category = '$cat'";
   3. $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query)); 
   4. $values = mysql_query($query);
   ?>
```

For some reason without line 3 it doesn't work.
By the way this is ultimately used to create an array passed to a google chart which is all fine. 
What am I doing wrong?

#### All code for reference;

```
   <?php
   $cat = strval($_GET['c']);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE Category = '$cat'";
   LINE UNDER QUESTION --> $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query)); 
   $values = mysql_query($query);
   $material = array();
   $quantity = array();
   $colour = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($values)) {
       array_push($material, $row['Material']);
       array_push($quantity, $row['Quantity']);
       array_push($colour, $row['Colour']);
   }
   ...Then all the google chart stuff....
   ?>
```

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Ok that's great but that's not the problem here. Although not ideal old mysql still works fine and changing to mysqli isn't going to fix this problem.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue, it works fine for me *even* when I revert to the old MySQL API. There must be something else going on in your code.

Comment: I've added more code but I know all the google chart stuff and the GET passing works fine. The issues lies somewhere in fetching the query.

Answer (score 0):

Specify columns in the select and use an index.
And make sure the $_GET value is validated.
You probably already have done this, but try the query in e.g. phpMyAdmin.
Maybe all this will help.

```
SELECT
    material,
    quantity,
    colour 
FROM
    stock
WHERE 
    Category = ...
ORDER BY ..
;
```

Comment: I tested the query in phpMyAdmin and it works but I tried implementing your query and that stopped it working at all. Really strange.

Comment: For reference, I'm counting the error as the google chart not loading (error data 0 cannot be string).

Comment: Did you get an error in phpMyAdmin? What does it say?

Comment: Well I queried what you suggested (ignoring the order by) and it returned the correct results. But when I then took that statement and replaced the $query line above (remembering to put the variable $cat back in) it stopped working alltogether

Comment: I'm starting to think it might be a google charts thing, but that doesn't make sense because I have fully functioning datatype checks in that section, and it also doesn't explain why line 3 is making it work?

Comment: Check the arrays if they are not empty after the loop.

Comment: And maybe 'my' query doesn't work because of the uppercases.

Comment: var_dump is very handy for this sort of thing, and / or a debugger.